# How do I code IF statement in Dax for power BI

Tags: dax

How do I code this in dax with IF statement.

Numbers 1-5 = Inadmissible

Numbers 5-25,27,28 = Family reasons

Number 26 = Medical reasons

Answer (score 0):

Use Switch():

```
SWITCH(
    TRUE()
    ,AND(value<29,value>26),”Family reason”
    ,value=26,”Medical reasons”
    ,value>4,”Family reasons”
    ,value>0,”inadmissible”
    ,”undefined”
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do exactly like you would do in Excel. Note that you would need a row context, so put the formula into a **calculated column**.

```
Result = 
IF( Sewa[Number] <= 5, "Inadmissible",
IF( Sewa[Number] <= 25, "Family reasons",
IF( Sewa[Number] = 26, "Medical reasons",
IF( Sewa[Number] > 26, "Family reasons"
))))
```

Comment: What about 0 and 29?

Comment: The table only has numbers between 1 and 28!

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: Sewa didn’t note that.